# how to select last-child or first-child elements just in parent? (css - html)

Tags: html, css, nav

I have problem with the select the `last-child` element!
I created page something like this for navbar:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">list numeber 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">list numeber 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub list item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub list item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub list item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">list numeber 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

with css something like this:

```
nav {
    background: yellow;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    padding: 10px 15px; 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
ul li:last-child {
    float: right;
    background: #ddd;
}
ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #eee;
    top: 39px;
    left: 0;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
ul li ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

i want to add BG for last-child (Sing out) in for Ul , but when see the sub-items, last-child of that get background like the parent. but i dont want to get color. how can i fix that...?
i dont want to use any class or id or JavaScript!
i there any way...?

[image]

TnX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ul li:last-child` to `nav > ul > li:last-child`.

The `>` character is the *direct-descendent selector*.

Comment: yes. that's right! tnx. but i have question that i use `ul > li:last-child` but it didnt work! why ...?

Comment: @AminRasouli Consult the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) and it will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

changes mentioned in comment line

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">list numeber 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">list numeber 2</a>
          <ul id="menu">// changes-here id is mentioned.
            <li><a href="#">sub list item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub list item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub list item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     <li><a href="#">list numeber 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Changes mentioned in comment line

```
nav {
  background: yellow;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  padding: 10px 15px; 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#menu li:last-child {// changes-here i refer the id of that menu
  float: right;
  background:green;
}
ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: 39px;
  left: 0;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

For Demo:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amsMg/)

Answer (score 0):

First, your padding on the li elements will have unpredictable results on different browsers. I suggest coding in Firefox or Chrome. instead, put the padding on the a tag.

```
li a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

li {
    /*padding: 10px 15px; */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Second, you can use a [decendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) to specify the depth of the CSS, and override less specific selectors.

```
ul li ul, ul li:last-child {
    background: #eee;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
    /*background: #eee;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 39px;
    left: 0;
}
```